# How to check if the new age range overlaps?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

My database table is called Timeline and it has these two columns, min_range and max_range. I am trying to insert a new age range, but I do not want it to overlap.

What I want it to return is true if the age overlaps and false if it does not.

Any help is appreciated.

This is what I have tried in Laravel. I tried to check if the new min_range falls in a range. It works for an existing range but also it does not allow me to insert a new one if the age does not fall in a range.

```
//check if range overlaps
$innerRange = Timeline::where('min_range', '>', $request->min_range) 
->where('max_range', '<', $request->min_range)->doesntExist();

if($innerRange){
    return response()->json(['error' => ['Range overlaps']]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segment (A,B) overlaps with (C,D) if (A,B) contains either C or D within it so you could do:

```
$innerRange = Timeline::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
      $query->where('min_range', '<=', $request->min_range)
            ->where('max_range', '>=', $request->min_range); // contains min range
})->orWhere(function ($query) use ($request) {
      $query->where('min_range', '<=', $request->max_range)
            ->where('max_range', '>=', $request->max_range); // contains max range
})->doesntExist();
```

Comment: This solution works for checking if either value falls in a range. Thank you very much. However, I overlooked one possibility, which was if I have an age range from 10-15 there is no condition to stop me from creating a range that contains an existing one like, 9-16. I know I didn't ask for that in my question, but I would appreciate it if you could direct me in the right direction to solve it.